# Azure Devops Releases Agent job's Agent configuration show 'Default (No agents)'

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm using Azure DevOps pipelines and for 'builds' I can define 'Hosted Ubuntu' agent (in my pipelines.yml file). But for 'releases' there's no way to edit yaml just the UI. The agent pool drop down list shows 'Default (no agents)'. I assume my problem is probably related to project permissions but haven't figured out what controls the visibility. On another account I see all the hosted agent options available.

[image]

Comment: Do you see the **Hosted Ubuntu 1604** listed in the `dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_settings/agentqueues` settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For the possible security permissions issue

Check that you are part of the group(s) assigned as **[User](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=azure-devops#security)** to the security of the app pool in question.

[image]

If this security operates like other **Allow, Deny, NotSet** permissions, then your occupation in a group that has less than **User** permission will revoke that permission, but I haven't seen any documentation about this.

### For the use of YAML in release pipelines

Yaml usage in the formal release pipeline hub is not supported. If you want to use `yaml` for your CD release, you're going to need to enable the new [multi-stage pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/stages?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) experience.

[image]

This allows you to create stages in your `.yml` file that relate to deployment functions in addition to the classic build functions.

I believe this removes your release tracking from the release hub and integrates it directly into the build hub.

This is still a new concept for Azure DevOps, as is the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema) and writing about it. I found [this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/whats-new-with-azure-pipelines/) to be helpful.

Because this new feature seems to be centered around AKS (or other Kubernetes services) and Docker, I'm not sure if this will help you by allowing you to specify the host in yaml, but you mentioned "release" and "yaml" in the same sentence, so I thought I would address that.

Comment: My user was not listed in this agent pool so that explains why I didn't see the hosted options.

Comment: Furthermore the multi-stage pipelines feature seems to be exactly right for me as I'm working with docker and AKS. I enabled the preview feature and will transform the current pipeline yamls toward this new functionality. Thanks for pointing that out!